# How to optimize 3D AABB Rotate (Java)

Tags: java, optimization, 3d, game-engine, aabb

recently I have been implementing 3D AABB's into my game engine, to accomplish rotations I use a simple method of rotating all 8 calculated corners around the center of the box using my Vector3f.rotate() method. But as you may notice below it is very inefficient. If you want to sort though the whole class here is the github (https://github.com/EquilibriumGames/Flounder-Engine/blob/master/src/flounder/physics/AABB.java) otherwise here is the snipit I need help with, I beleve there could be simpler methods out there but I want to know what you think. Thank you!

```
        // Creates the 8 AABB corners and rotates them.
    Vector3f FLL = new Vector3f(destination.minExtents.x, destination.minExtents.y, destination.minExtents.z);
    Vector3f.rotate(FLL, rotation, FLL);

    Vector3f FLR = new Vector3f(destination.maxExtents.x, destination.minExtents.y, destination.minExtents.z);
    Vector3f.rotate(FLR, rotation, FLR);

    Vector3f FUL = new Vector3f(destination.minExtents.x, destination.maxExtents.y, destination.minExtents.z);
    Vector3f.rotate(FUL, rotation, FUL);

    Vector3f FUR = new Vector3f(destination.maxExtents.x, destination.maxExtents.y, destination.minExtents.z);
    Vector3f.rotate(FUR, rotation, FUR);

    Vector3f BUR = new Vector3f(destination.maxExtents.x, destination.maxExtents.y, destination.maxExtents.z);
    Vector3f.rotate(BUR, rotation, BUR);

    Vector3f BUL = new Vector3f(destination.minExtents.x, destination.maxExtents.y, destination.maxExtents.z);
    Vector3f.rotate(BUL, rotation, BUL);

    Vector3f BLR = new Vector3f(destination.maxExtents.x, destination.minExtents.y, destination.maxExtents.z);
    Vector3f.rotate(BLR, rotation, BLR);

    Vector3f BLL = new Vector3f(destination.minExtents.x, destination.minExtents.y, destination.maxExtents.z);
    Vector3f.rotate(BLL, rotation, BLL);

    destination.minExtents = Maths.min(FLL, Maths.min(FLR, Maths.min(FUL, Maths.min(FUR, Maths.min(BUR, Maths.min(BUL, Maths.min(BLR, BLL)))))));
    destination.maxExtents = Maths.max(FLL, Maths.max(FLR, Maths.max(FUL, Maths.max(FUR, Maths.max(BUR, Maths.max(BUL, Maths.max(BLR, BLL)))))));
```